# how to create a custom drop down menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanna make a custom menu that appears when user touches a button.  here is an image of what i want to do exactly.

[image]

If anyone can point me in the direction on how to do this i would greatly appreciate it.  I want them to be able to click on it and then it input a specific text.  Thank you for any help  you can give me

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Sliding Drawer:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

[image]

---

Or the new 'Ribbon Menu' this has other names as well, it's the menu off the new YubTube app or the Facebook app.

https://github.com/darvds/RibbonMenu

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here:
You can create a dialog activity with a translucent background and lay it out however you'd like.
Then you can just call startActivityForResult() on it.

Here's an example:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TranslucentActivity.html

Comment: let me try this and see if this gives me the desired effect